# broke at the seams?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Does broke at the seams means destroy completely? I couldn't find a definition for it, so I was hoping someone would enlighten me.

> He broke his hope at the seams and now he's a desperate man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Break at the seams" makes sense but is not how I know the idiom. Rather:

> **[come apart at the seams](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+apart+at+the+seams)**
>
> 1. To be approaching failure.
>    *Boy, this party is really coming apart at the seams. First, there was the issue with the caterer, and now half the guests aren't coming.*
> 2. To become very emotional.
>    *Poor Jane really came apart at the seams during the funeral service.*

It's hard to tell from this snippet (more context is always better!) but the author may be extending this idiom to mean that the man has suffered a mental breakdown or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto randomhead. Let me just add a comment:

"Seams" are where pieces of cloth are sewn together to make clothing. So literally, for a piece of clothing to "come apart at the seams" means that the stitches holding it together have torn loose.

I don't know how "came apart at the seams" came to mean "failed badly". Is it worse if your shirt tears at the seams than tears in some other place? But that's the idiom.

I've also heard "fell apart at the seams" and "tore apart at the seams". I don't recall ever hearing "broke at the seams". I don't know if the writer just bungled the idiom or if he had some reason for the unusual wording.

Comment: In the literal meaning, seams are often where the clothing comes apart; the cloth pieces hold together better.

Comment: @Mary Sure. The seams are the weakest point. So to "come apart at the seams" literally means to fail at the weakest point. But why is that the idiom? People generally use it to mean "fail badly", without any connotation about failing at the weakest point.

Comment: It's the simplest way for something to collapse entirely.